How do i model this part?
Does anyone know how to model this part of a robot?

Cut off a UV sphere and extrude down:

Cut off these faces:

Fill:

Move the edges until you get something round:

Bevel if you want to use a Subdivision Surface modifier:


Thanks! Is it possible to sharpen the front edges? (For subdivision surface)

You can bevel, see my edit
